# xbox one app issues to connect to console

Tags: apps

My console connection always fails, I've already disabled segmentation on my WiFi AP and I already separated SSID like Microsoft support recommends. The Error Code is just not providing any useful information:

Error 80000001e

Comment: Have you tried [these troubleshooting steps](https://support.xbox.com/en-GB/xbox-one/errors/error-code-8000001e)?

Comment: @indrek. I did and solution 1 from your links work alright, but this means every time this happens i'll have to uninstall and reinstall Xbox smart-glass (already on my 5th iteration so far), so its not much of a solution. There should be a better long term solution or workaround. Or just a better app. I have tried it with 2 windows phones so far so I don't know if its related to the phone OS or just the app in general.